# trying to read values off another test app's shared pref file

Tags: android

On my app, I am trying to read values off another test app's shared pref file. It holds a string value. I am trying to use the following code on my app but no value displays for the Item1:

file file = new File("/data/data/com.appmanager/shared_prefs/appmanager_conf.xml");

```
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(file);
        pin = document.getElementsByTagName("ITEM1").item(0).getTextContent();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I did this first below:

String key = ""; try { con = createPackageContext("com.application1", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY); SharedPreferences prefs = con.getSharedPreferences("passmanager_conf", MODE_PRIVATE); key = prefs.getString("ITEM1", "Couldn't Find"); Log.i("mainActivity", "My item is " + key); } catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){ Log.e("Not Data Shared", e.toString()); }

Comment: 1)There is no promise in Android that the path will work.  You shouldn't make any assumptions about the directory layout of where your app is on disk or where another app is on disk.

2)Two different apps don't have read access to each other's files.

Comment: my app has the same sharedUserId as the app it was trying to read from.

Comment: I did try it this way first but it didn't work: String key = "";

        try {
    con = createPackageContext("com.application1", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);


        SharedPreferences prefs = con.getSharedPreferences("passmanager_conf", MODE_PRIVATE);
       
        key = prefs.getString("ITEM1", "Couldn't Find");
    Log.i("mainActivity", "My item is " + key);

} catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
    Log.e("Not Data Shared", e.toString());
}

Comment: actually just thinking I could do this via Content Provider possibly